# How do I do html forms with sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Is there some utilities available so that I could easily encapsulate form fields passed in requests in an object or do I have to create it myself by parsing fields from params in every request?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Yes**, since Sinatra 0.9 you can use Rails-like nested parameters:

You just declare your form as:

```
<form>
  <input ... name="post[title]" />
  <input ... name="post[body]" />
  <input ... name="post[author]" />
</form>
```

And then you just have to do:

```
@post = params[:post]
```

to fetch all the parameters in an object.

More information in [Learn Ruby the Hard Way](http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex51.html)

Comment: Just a heads up, that link isn't live anymore.